# Sqlite3 inserts to non-indexed table taking longer as table gets larger

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

Without getting into too much detail, I have a process in my iOS app that parses XML and inserts (sometimes up to 10s or 100s of) thousands of records into an Sqlite3 table.

For speed, I have no indexes on the table, and I'm inserting records into an in memory temporary table first then moving them over to the final table in batches of 400. Neither the temporary table or filesystem table have any indexes.

The problem I'm noticing is that at the beginning of the process, it takes about a 10th of a second to flush the 400 records to disk. Then with each flush, it takes longer and longer, where after a minute or two, it's taking 3 seconds to flush the 400 records. The longer it goes, the longer it takes. Each flush takes about a 1 to 2 tenths of a second longer than the previous one.

Since I'm not using any indexes, can anyone explain why this is happening and recommend a solution?

**Update 1:**
I tried setting `PRAGMA syncronous = OFF;` and while that sped things up a little, it still get a fraction of a second slower with every `INSERT SELECT` to the point where it is multiple seconds for every flush after a few thousand rows. I'll keep trying other optimizations to see if I can get to the bottom of this...

**Update 2:**
Clarification on what I'm doing: I'm inserting the records as they are parsed into a temporary table that's in memory until the count reaches 400 as counted by an int in Objective-C code. Once the record count is 400, I'm doing a single INSERT SELECT to move the rows into the table on disk, then I'm doing a DELETE * from the memory table. I'm timing each part. Sqlite3 optimizes DELETE * when it has no WHERE clause so that it's like dropping and recreating the table, and it is very quick, less than 100th of a second. It's only the INSERT SELECT from the memory table to the disk table that is decreasing in speed each time. That query starts out taking about 0.1 seconds, and after each batch of 400 records that is inserted, the query takes about .1 to .2 seconds longer than the last one, until it's eventually taking multiple seconds to move the 400 rows from memory to disk each time.

**Update 3:** Here are my table creation statements and the statement I'm using to move records from memory to disk. There are no keys at all. And yes my sqlite is configured so that the temporary table is in memory not disk.

The temporary table in memory:

1. `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE allSongsTemp (title TEXT, songId TEXT, artist TEXT, album TEXT, genre TEXT, coverArtId TEXT, path TEXT, suffix TEXT, transcodedSuffix TEXT, duration INTEGER, bitRate INTEGER, track INTEGER, year INTEGER, size INTEGER);`

The table on disk:

1. `CREATE TABLE allSongsUnsorted (title TEXT, songId TEXT, artist TEXT, album TEXT, genre TEXT, coverArtId TEXT, path TEXT, suffix TEXT, transcodedSuffix TEXT, duration INTEGER, bitRate INTEGER, track INTEGER, year INTEGER, size INTEGER);`

The queries to flush the memory records to disk:

1. `INSERT INTO allSongsUnsorted SELECT * FROM allSongsTemp;`
2. `DELETE * FROM allSongsTemp;`

**The query that is taking longer and longer each time is #3, the `INSERT SELECT`. The `DELETE` takes about 1/100th of a second each time.**

Comment: Is it possible that you've somehow managed to join the two tables when doing the SELECT such that the target table is being referenced?  Are you sure you don't have a primary key declared or some such, causing SQLite to enforce uniqueness?

Comment: So how many entries do you have in the target table by the time it's taking, say, 4 seconds to do the inserts?

Comment: What happens if you try the following two experiments: (1) DROP allSongsTemp and reCREATE it instead of DELETEing and (2) use a standard on-disk table instead of a memory table (of course, it will be slower, but is it consistent?)  I'm thinking of the possibility of some kind of memory fragmentation in the TEMPORARY table.

Comment: Larry can you add your #1 suggestion as an answer so I can accept it. :) I had thought that might be the problem but because the DELETE is so quick and I had read that Sqlite3 optimizes `DELETE *` as a `DROP/CREATE` I figured that couldn't be the problem and didn't even test it! Shame on me lol. It's always the thing that it **just can't be** hehe. It looks like, at least for in memory tables, it's better to `DROP/CREATE` than to `DELETE`, optimizations be darned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Larry Lustig called it in the comments to the question, but doesn't seem to be around anymore to create an answer.

Dropping and re-creating the table instead of doing `DELETE *` did the trick. It seems that though the delete was quick, it was causing some kind of fragmentation in memory that was slowing down each subsequent read. Unless I misread the sqlite3 docs, a `DELETE *` is supposed to be optimized as a `DROP; CREATE;` but it seems that may not be exectly the case for temporary memory tables (or maybe even filesystem tables, but I would need to test that to verify as this issue could very well only affect memory tables).

Answer (score 0):

Read up on transactions, and why you should use them.  If you do individual inserts then each insert must go through a start/end transaction cycle, with considerable overhead.  When doing bulk insert/update operations always do a start transaction first.

Comment: I'm familiar with transactions but the slowdown in question is happening on a single INSERT SELECT statement, not multiple separate INSERTs.

Comment: I tested it just to verify and wrapping in a transaction makes no difference in speed. Like I said it's only a single query, so transactions have nothing to do with it. Are sqlite3 tables inherently slower to insert into as they get larger, even without indexes? We're not even talking a huge table here just a few thousand rows.

Comment: Not clear -- are you doing the copies one after the other, after accumulating all your records, or are you doing each after 400 records accumulate?  Is it possible that the slow-down is on the query side, as the number of records increases?

Comment: I updated the question to include the table definitions and the INSERT SELECT I'm using. No index, primary key, unique constraints or anything...

Answer (score 0):

What do your keys look like, and do you have any unique columns/constraints on this table?  A definition (with changed column names if the real names are too revealing) would help diagnose the problem, but my guess would be a sneak unique constraint somewhere in your table definition.

Comment: I updated the question to include the table definitions and the INSERT SELECT query I'm using. No indexes or unique constraints. Yet somehow it takes longer and longer each time as if it's rebuilding an index or something.